# How to Store textField value in nextViewController String

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, nsstring

i have text field and i want to store this value in string in nextViewController and the string sending with url. how it is possible?

```
if ([textField.text length]== 0) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DigiPhoto" message:@"Please Enter The Code" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
} else {

    DigiPhotoTableViewController * photoView = [[DigiPhotoTableViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoView animated:YES];

}
```

In NextViewController i want to do This how it added the textField please help me.

```
scanCode = textField.text;
NSString * urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url %@",scanCode];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (!conn)
{
    responseData = nil;
    NSLog(@"Connection Error");
}
```

Comment: you have to use delegate method,otherwise you have to create property on another viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one property in Main view Controller

```
@interface DigiPhotoTableViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* dataString;
@end
```

and send value from other view controller using mainViewcontroller object like this first Import DigiPhotoTableViewController

after use main class object and send value

```
if ([textField.text length]== 0) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DigiPhoto" message:@"Please Enter The Code" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
} else {

    DigiPhotoTableViewController * photoView = [[DigiPhotoTableViewController alloc]init];
    photoView.dataString = textField.text;;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoView animated:YES];

}
```

For more details visit this link [Pass a value from one ViewController to another ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178600/pass-a-value-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-viewcontroller/24178697#24178697)

Comment: i want to send textfield entered value

Comment: I have updated my answer according to you... Please pass your textField there ...

Comment: where create new property .. remove readonly from this. sorry for this ... try again after remove readonly ....

Comment: and the dataString Value sending From NextViewController to DetailedViewController. how to send it?

Comment: It will send using through this code , now you want to use this in DetailedViewController. Am I right ?  If I am right then try to use dataString in DetailedViewController in 

 NSLog(@"Data Print %@",self.dataString); 

Try this you will get value in DetailedViewController and any where can use in  DetailedViewController using this type self.dataString    ...

Comment: Thak You Very Much Joge

Answer (score 0):

Create a property named scanCode as below

```
if ([textField.text length]== 0) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DigiPhoto" message:@"Please Enter The Code" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
} else {

    DigiPhotoTableViewController * photoView = [[DigiPhotoTableViewController alloc]init];
    photoView.scanCode=textField.text;//assigning textfield value to scanCodeString
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoView animated:YES];

}

//Next View COntroller..Modify code as below.

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *scanCode;

//textField.text=scanCode;
NSString * urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url %@",scanCode];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (!conn)
{
    responseData = nil;
    NSLog(@"Connection Error");
}
```

Hope it helps you..